# which tense should we use in these conditional sentences?

Tags: conditional-constructions

These 2 sentences are in my course book but I doubt its accuracy and I have to choose one of them. It's under zero/first conditional category.

which one is correct and why

> 1) Don't worry. Rob **will have passed** the exam if he **studied** enough.
>
> 2) Don't worry. Rob **has passed** the exam if he **studied** enough.

please tell me if both are correct with differences in meaning or

If none of them are correct, give me the right form.

Comment: Both are grammatical.

Comment: I think the correct form is : Rob **would have passed** the exam if he studied enough.

Comment: The first one is correct but only in a very specific situation where the speaker was speaking about this hypothetically, knowing that Rob had been taking the exam but not yet knowing its results nor how much Rob had studied. I would imagine two girlfriends, one comforting the other. I just mean that I think this example is a little bit forced.

Comment: I'm having difficulty thinking of a context for the second one. Not sure why it's getting upvotes for grammaticality, but probably just a lapse on my part :O :). @Clare, could you please help provide a possible context for the second one wherein it would be grammatical?

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang why does it use '' future perfect not future simple? Is there any difference?

Comment: Honestly, as I had mentioned, I think the example is a little forced. I think they were trying to force an example for the grammar point they had been trying to make.

Comment: In the meantime, the difference would be the situation in which you would use one over the other. For future perfect (your first example sentence), I've described above the only situation I can imagine (at this time, though there may be more) where it would be appropriate. In the meantime, simple future is acceptable for most situations as well as for the situation I've described above.

Answer (score 1):

Your first sentence is correct

> Don't worry. Rob **will have passed** the exam if he **studied** enough.

You would say this *after the test*, *will have passed* is the hypothetical scenario given the condition "*if* he *studied* enough*"

You could also say *after studying*

> Don't worry. Rob **will pass** the exam if he **studied** enough.

Or while he is *still studying*

> Don't worry. Rob **will pass** the exam if he **studies** enough.

Your second sentence is almost correct

> Don't worry. Rob **has passed** the exam if he **studied** enough.

better might be

> Don't worry. Rob **passed** the exam *since* he **studied** enough.

which is a statement of fact and might be a follow up to your first sentence.

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for a clearer answer considering perfect tenses . what are they trying to say using ''future perfect''? or the second one why ''present perfect''

Comment: The conditional is real past: Rob has done the test, and he has got his result, but the 1st and 2nd persons in the example don't know the result. In such a case (a single event in the past that is not certain from the speakers point of view), is example 2 of the OP grammatical and correct or not?